# Smart loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I'm trying to construct a loop in R. You don't need to know the theory about time series to answer this question. It's just a matter of coding.

Let'simplify things a lot
Suppose I have the following dataset:

```
v1=c(rep(NA,20),10.98222,11.00063,11.01974,11.03949,11.05954,11.07969,
     11.10034,11.12046,11.14027,11.1617,11.17994,11.19107,11.19876,11.21962,11.24644,
     11.26818,11.26932,11.27054,11.28308,11.30279,11.34147,11.32627,11.52882,
     11.58255,  11.51651,   11.57573,   11.63417,   11.65027,   11.66791,   11.68818,
     11.70148,  11.71987,   11.74954,   11.77637,   11.8121,    11.85658,   11.90377,   11.95315,
     12.04978,  12.16569,   12.21285,   12.23659,   12.23843,   12.31716,   12.33681,   12.31562,   12.2742,    
     12.25395,  12.24532    ,12.26309)
v2=c(11.47885,  11.51671,   11.54449,   11.57741,   11.60955,   11.66566,
     11.71694,  11.76816,   11.81797,   11.87313,   11.93417,   11.99726,   
     12.0687,   12.1522,    12.20797,   12.27495,   12.33479,   12.37249,
     12.42329,  12.48625,   12.56286,   12.63491,   12.70479,   12.75831,
     12.80608,  12.85546,   12.89077,   12.93107,   12.96787,   12.99742,
     13.02395,  13.05983,   13.08719,   13.11153,   13.13959,   13.15648,   
     13.17543,  13.19983,   13.218, 13.23999,   13.25284,   13.26138,
     13.29228,  13.3346,    13.36606,   13.38624,   13.39982,   13.41702,
     13.42771,  13.43689,   13.43766,   13.4355,    13.43529,   13.43684,
     13.4486,   13.45973,   13.45641,   13.46292,   13.47876,   13.50551,   
     13.51974,  13.52184,   13.52552,   13.55106,   13.55552,   13.54598,
     13.53144,  13.52104,   13.51545,   13.51223)


df=data.frame(country=c(rep("ALB",70),rep("ITA",70)),year=c(rep(1950:2019)),lncap_worker=c(v1,v2))
```

To objective is to know the order of integration for each series which means testing the cov-stationarity of each time series. One by one, I write

```
alb=ts(na.omit(df$lncap_worker[df$country=="ALB"]))
library(tseries)
adf.test(alb)
adf.test(diff(diff(alb)))

ita=ts(na.omit(df$lncap_worker[df$country=="ITA"]))
library(tseries)
adf.test(ita)
adf.test(diff(diff(ita)))
```

Now, for both countries, the series are I(2), i.e., the series are cov-stationary after differentiating twice. R tells me that because only by differentiating twice the series,
the function adf.test returns a p-value<0.05

The issue is that I'm dealing with a massive dataset with more than 150 countries.
I tried to construct the following loop:

```
# List of unique countries in your dataset
unique_countries <- unique(df$country)

# Initialize a list to store the results
integration_orders <- list()

# Loop through each country
for (country in unique_countries) {
  country_data <- subset(df, country == country)
  time_series <- country_data$lncap_worker
  
  # Remove missing values from the time series
  time_series <- na.omit(time_series)
  
  # Initialize the integration order counter
  order_of_integration <- 0
  
  # Perform ADF test until the series becomes stationary
  while (adf.test(time_series)$p.value >= 0.05) {
    time_series <- diff(time_series)
    order_of_integration <- order_of_integration + 1
  }
  
  # Store the integration order for the current country
  integration_orders[[country]] <- order_of_integration
}

# Convert the list to a dataframe
integration_df <- data.frame(country = unique_countries,
                             integration_order = unlist(integration_orders))

# Print the output
print(integration_df)
```

However, the outcome tells me the series are I(1) when clearly they are I(2)

Comment: First of all, we need a small, reproducible set of data which causes the apparent error!   Since your loop code is **not** the same as your `v1,v2` sample code, the sample isn't helpful.    And next: how exactly are you certain your `df` country data are in fact I(2)?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft thanks for the comment. My loop code is tailored for my v1,v2 sample code. Is there something wrong?  Have I missed something? My df country data are I(2) because only when you take the second difference of each time series, you can reject the null hypothesis of the ADF test (at alpha=.05) which says non-stationarity (as you can see from my coding example above).